# Angular universal doesn't load fonts on server side

Tags: angular, fonts, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have custom fonts loaded inside main.scss  like that:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: helvetica-geo-roman;
  src: url(/assets/fonts/helvetica-geo/Linotype-HelveticaNeueLTGEO55Roman.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

My angular.json looks like that:

```
    "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/browser",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                "aot": true,
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles/main.scss"
                ],
                ...
```

So as you can see, I bootstrap main.scss file, so I think that fonts should be loaded before view rendered. but server returns view without fonts, and after a half second, browser fixes and sets fonts as expected but I have flicker. so problem is that server doesn't load fonts. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The server side is just responsible for rendering the markup / html of your page - the browser still has to take this and render it to the display.

In order to minimise time to first paint the browser will render text using a different font whilst it is downloading the requested one, this is to be expected and desirable.

One thing you can do is specify fallback fonts to be used whilst the desired font is loading, and chose ones that are as close as possible to the final font to reduce the jarringness of the transition.

Edit: it seems that chrome actually will render the text as blank whilst downloading the font, but Firefox will use the default font, you can read more here https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/technical_considerations